# how to convert \/Date(1567074191725)\/ to date in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I am not able to convert into proper date like

```
29/9/2019
```

from the

```
\/Date(1567074191725)\/
```

data.

Sample data

```
[{"timestamp":"\/Date(1567074191725)\/","dataFrame":"ASQAAA=="}]
```

Code

```
var values = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.records));
```

> //data table code

```
{
    title: "DATE", data: "timestamp",
    render: function (data) {
        var updDate = UtcToIst(data);
        return updDate;
    }
},
function UtcToIst(data) {
    var dt = new Date(data);
    return dt;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to extract the milliseconds of the data with `substr` method, and then you only pass this number to `Date` constructor.

```
new Date(parseInt(data.substr(6, 13)))
```